Arranging the result of Factor
Could I locate my differentials like dx, at the end of expression? I tried Collect function but the order seems to follow canonical order.

   dx /: dx^2 := 0
Factor[Expand[(x + dx)^2 - x^2  ]]
Collect[2 dx x, dx]    (*How could I get 2 x dx?*)


Times has the attribute Orderless, which mean products are automatically sorted into standard order. Since multiplication is commutative, what does it matter? Is it a question of formatting output for presentation or a paper?

Maybe consider Times[2, x, d[x]], which has the desired order in the standard order. You could probably use \[DoubleStruckD]x for this, too, although it looks like \[DifferentialD].

There are many questions about changing the order of factors (or terms) in Mathematica, such as: How do I reassign canonical ordering of symbols?, How to sort arguments of Times in nonstandard order?, Order of Terms in Algebraic Expression

The box form of a b is RowBox[{"a", " ", "b"}], so we can format something times dx as unevaluated nested Times:
ClearAll[dx]

dx /: dx^n_Integer /; n > 1 := 0;
MakeBoxes[p_ dx, form_] := 
  RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", MakeBoxes[p, form], ")"}], " ", "dx"}] /; 
   Head@Unevaluated@p === Plus;
MakeBoxes[p_ dx, form_] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes[p, form], " ", "dx"}];

Expand[(x + dx)^3 - x^3]
Collect[Expand[(x + %) (x + dx)], dx] (* to show use of output *)
Collect[Expand[(x + %) (x + dx)], dx] (* to show use of output *)
(*
3 x^2 dx
x^2 + (x + 3 x^3) dx
x^2 + x^3 + (x + 2 x^2 + 3 x^4) dx
*)

To unset the formatting:
MakeBoxes[p_ dx, form_] =.


Differential
If what you are trying is to get the differential, instead of forcing $dx^2$ to be zero, perhaps is best to use Series and SeriesCoefficient?
With[
    {
        ser = Series[(x + dx)^2 - x^2 , {dx, 0, 1}]
    },
    SeriesCoefficient[ser, 1]
]
(* 2 x *)

Display
If you are just after $(2\, x)\, dx$ instead of $2\, dx\, x$, you will not change the order factors are displayed using Collect. As explained by @MichaelE2

Times has the attribute Orderless, which mean products are automatically sorted into standard order.



